# NullReferenceException when restoring a MvxDialogActivity

Tags: dialog, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Right after having my application killed by Android due to some multitasking issues I can see one of my activities `MyActivity` : `MvxDialogActivity` crashing when the application is trying to recreated it.

That is, everything works fine before moving my application to the background and starting switching between other applications until the next message appears on console (DDMS):

```
I/ActivityManager( 333): No longer want com.my.app (pid 4444): hidden #22
```

When reopening the application, it tries to recreate its activites and so one of them is crashing with the next stack trace:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextStack`1<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext>> () <0x00038>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextStackRegistration`1<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext>.get_Stack () <0x0001f>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextStackRegistration`1<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext>..ctor (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext) <0x00017>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.CommonInflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup,Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Binders.MvxBindingLayoutInflatorFactory) <0x0004b>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.BindingInflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup) <0x0004f>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.BindingInflate (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextOwner,int,Android.Views.ViewGroup) <0x000c7>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Droid.Views.MvxDialogActivity.SetContentView (int) <0x0001f>
at Droid.UI.Impl.MyActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0008f>
```

I think it is happening due to some mistake I did when trying to setup the MvvmCross inside my project.

Are there any other reasons for this crash?
May some of you give a direction about how can I get this crash fixed?

Here follows my `Setup.cs` file:

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidDialogSetup 
{
    public Setup (Context applicationContext)
        : base (applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp ()
    {
        return new MvvmCrossApplication ();
    }
}


public class MvvmCrossApplication : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize ()
    {
        RegisterAppStart<ApplicationViewModel>();
    }
}
```

It appears that when Android is recreating my App, it is instantiating a new `MyActivity` instance before the initial MvvmCross setup gets completed. Maybe because when the App was killed, there was a valid instance of the same class. Is it possible to be happening?

This is an screenshot of what my `MyActivity` class presents on the screen:

[image: MyActivity custom layout]

It is a MvxDialogActivity which has:

- An actionBar;
- A custom layout (containing a custom ListView with the next id: `android:id="@android:id/list"`); and
- A Root element which is updated accordingly to its ViewModel updates.

Comment: If you think this is due to some setup mistake in setup, then can you include this code? Or can you repro the issue in a sample?

Comment: @Stuart, Thank you again for helping me. I have been updating all my non-MvxActivities to start inheriting from MvxActivities classes and everything is properly working, there is just this specific case about this `MyActivity` : `MvxDialogActivity` class.

Answer (score 0):

From the call stack it looks like `MyActivity.OnCreate` is calling `SetContentView`

Android.Dialog-based activities do **not** call `SetContentView` during their `OnCreate` implementations

Some examples of these dialog views are in:

- DialogExamples - e.g. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Droid/Views/FirstView.cs
- N=23 - https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-23-Dlg

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question again. Actually I really need to call the SetContentView method because I need a custom layout. I am just wondering why I am able to start `MyActivity` instances from code without any problems but when Android is trying to recreate it right after killing my app it can't ending with a crash. This crash does not happen if I switch between other apps and return to my app without it being killed by Android when running in background mode.

Comment: You've written custom activity code which is not included in the question. I've tried to help. I can't do any more really. If you think it's an issue within Mvx, please provide a complete working sample (you can base this on an existing sample) and open an issue that repros the issue.